# Как достать файл базы данных SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Прочел что она лежит по такому пути - "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/", но не могу достать файл, получаю FileNotFoundException. В чем может быть проблема?

```
 // File dbFile = new File ("/data/data/com/example/dmitryvedmed/databases/myDB8.db");
//  File dbFile = new File (context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "myDB8.db");
//  File dbFile = new File (context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/" + "myDB8.db");
//  File dbFile = new File (context.getPackageName() + "/databases/" + "myDB8.db");
    File dbFile =  (context.getDatabasePath("myDB8.db"));
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).